# Meteor findOne result with React

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I would like display my Article component with Meteor and React, but my Post.findOne() return undefined, and i don't understand why :

```
class Article extends Component {

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      this.props.loading
        ? <span>Loading...</span>
        : <h1>{this.props.match.params.slug}</h1>
    );
  }

}

Article.propTypes = {
  post: React.PropTypes.object,
  loading: React.PropTypes.bool
}

ArticleContainer = createContainer(({ slug }) => {
  const postHandle = Meteor.subscribe('post');
  const post = Post.findOne({
    'slug': "super-test"
  });
  const loading = !postHandle.ready();

  return {
    loading,
    post
  };
}, Article);

export default ArticleContainer;
```

Publish method :

```
Meteor.publish('post', () => {
  return Post.find();
});
```

the console.log return this :

```
Object { match: Object, location: Object, history: Object, staticContext: undefined, loading: true, post: undefined }  app.js:392:7
Object { match: Object, location: Object, history: Object, staticContext: undefined, loading: true, post: Object }  app.js:392:7
```

My route :

```
<AppLayout path='/blog/:slug' component={ArticleContainer} />
```

Anyone can help me about this ?

Thank you community !

Comment: how does your publication method look like? Please add it's code to your question.

Comment: Article.protoTypes should be Article.propTypes

Comment: Hi, i've update my code on first post

Answer (score 0):

It is `undefined` because subscriptions are async. Your component will render even if your `post` isn't fetched. You should use your already defined `loading` property:

```
class Article extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      loading
        ? <span>Loading...</span>
        : <h1>{this.props.match.params.slug}</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi fmilani, i've try with loading, i've no result : always return loading. But my console.log is different (see my first post updated) : loading is alway at true

Comment: That's weird, because on the second log with have the `post` object, which would mean that the subscription was ready and then `loading` would be `false`.